# What is the Struts2 equivalent for <bean:message> tag with property attribute in Struts1? For example:<bean:message name="user" property="label" />

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tags, struts

In Struts 1 the **`<bean:message>`** tag is usually used with the key attribute in order to get the message from the properties file by specifying the message-key in the key attribute.

And in struts 2 we do that by using either **`<s:text>`** or **`<s:property>`** tags.

Consider the below example:
In struts 1,
`<bean:message key="user.name.required"/>`

The equivalent in Struts 2 is,

`<s:text name="user.name.required" />` or
`<s:property value="getText('user.name.required')"/>` where,
`user.name.required = Name is required`
is the content of the properties file.

But I'm confused with a different scenario.
**`<bean:message name="user" property="label" />`**

for this, I tried `<s:property value="getText('label')"/>`
but the value returned is the string `"label"` instead of the message string `"User data is missing"`

and I also tried `<s:property value="label"/>`
But the value returned is message key i.e. `"user.data.missing"` instead of the message string `"User data is missing"`

`<bean:message name="user" property="label" />` in Struts 1 returns the message User data is missing.
where,
`user.data.missing=User data is missing` 
is the content of the properties file.

My question is how do I achieve this in Struts 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
<s:property value="getText(label)"/>
```

where `label` is a variable in the value stack which contains a message key i.e. `"user.data.missing"` .